Error while generating release build or running gradle task gradle :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
I'm encountering an issue while trying to generate a release build or run the gradle :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 task for my Android application.
My Android project has two modules: app and core
The build process fails with an error message that looks something like this:
Missing class com.atech.core.module.FirebaseModule_ProvideFirebaseFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.atech.core.module.FirebaseModule_ProviderFirebaseAuthFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.atech.core.module.RoomModule_ProvideDatabaseFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.atech.core.module.RoomModule_ProvideResearchHubDaoFactory (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get())
Missing class com.atech.core.room.ResearchHubDao (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get() and 6 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.room.model.ResearchMapper (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.GetAllUserCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.getAllUserCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.AuthUseCases (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.AuthUseCases com.atech.research.ui.screens.login.LoginViewModel.authUseCases and 8 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.DeleteAllUseCases (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.DeleteAllUseCases com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.deleteAllUseCases() and 1 other context)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.DeleteUserByIdUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.DeleteUserByIdUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.deleteUserByIdUseCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.FireStoreUseCases (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get() and 3 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.GetAllResearchUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.FireStoreUseCases com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.fireStoreUseCases() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.GetAllUserCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.GetAllUserCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.getAllUserCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.GetUserByIdUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.GetUserByIdUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.getUserByIdUseCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.GetUserDetailsUseFromAuthCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.AuthUseCases com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.authUseCases() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.HasUserUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.HasUserUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.hasUserUseCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.InsertUserUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.InsertUserUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.insertUserUseCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.IsResearchExistUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.IsResearchExistUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.isResearchExistUseCase() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.IsUserLoggedInUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.AuthUseCases com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.authUseCases() and 3 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.LogInUseCase (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.LogInUseCase com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.logInUseCase() and 1 other context)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.LogInWithGoogle (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.AuthUseCases com.atech.research.DaggerResearchHub_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.authUseCases() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.use_cases.WishListUseCases (referenced from: com.atech.core.use_cases.WishListUseCases com.atech.research.ui.screens.student.ui.research.main.ResearchViewModel.wishListUseCases and 10 other contexts)
Missing class com.atech.core.utils.JsonKt (referenced from: void com.atech.research.ui.screens.student.ui.research.detail.compose.ComposableSingletons$ResearchDetailsScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int))
Missing class com.atech.core.utils.State$Error (referenced from: void com.atech.research.ui.screens.login.LoginViewModel$logIn$1$1.invoke(com.atech.core.utils.State))
Missing class com.atech.core.utils.State$Loading (referenced from: void com.atech.research.ui.screens.login.LoginViewModel$logIn$1$1.invoke(com.atech.core.utils.State))
Missing class com.atech.core.utils.State$Success (referenced from: void com.atech.research.ui.screens.login.LoginViewModel$logIn$1$1.invoke(com.atech.core.utils.State))
Missing class com.atech.core.utils.State (referenced from: void com.atech.research.ui.screens.login.LoginViewModel$logIn$1$1.invoke(com.atech.core.utils.State) and 1 other context)


I have tried the following steps to resolve the problem:

Clean and rebuild the project
Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio
Update Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin to the latest versions
Check for any potential conflicts or incompatibilities with third-party libraries
Ensure that all required dependencies are correctly declared in the project

However, none of these steps have resolved the issue so far.
Here is my (App module) build.gradle.kts file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.googleAndroidLibrariesMapsplatformSecretsGradlePlugin)
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.atech.research"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.atech.research"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.14"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
            excludes += "META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation(project(":core"))

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material.icons.extended)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    implementation(libs.play.service.auth)

    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
    ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)

    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)

    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
    releaseImplementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
    implementation(libs.firebase.message)


    implementation(libs.coil.kt.coil.compose)
    implementation(libs.coil.svg)
    implementation(libs.lottie.compose)

    implementation(libs.richtext.commonmark)
    implementation(libs.richtext.ui.material3)

}

(Core module) build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("androidx.room")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.atech.core"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")

        room {
            schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)

    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.gson)

    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)


    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
    releaseImplementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
    implementation(libs.firebase.firestore)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)

}

lib.version.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.4.0"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.51.1"
hiltAndroidVersion = "2.51.1"
hiltNavigationFragment = "1.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.24"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
ksp-version = "1.9.24-1.0.20"
hiltAndroid = "2.51.1"
hiltAndroidPlugin = "2.50"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
roomKtx = "2.6.1"
roomVersion = "2.6.1"
junitJunit = "4.13.2"
androidxJunit = "1.1.5"
espressoCoreVersion = "3.5.1"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.12.0"
firebaseBom = "33.0.0"
googleGmsGoogleServices = "4.4.1"
googleAndroidLibrariesMapsplatformSecretsGradlePlugin = "2.0.1"
materialIconsExtended = "1.6.7"
gson-version = "2.10.1"
coilCompose = "2.6.0"
lottieCompose = "6.4.0"
richtextCommonmark = "0.20.0"
play-service-auth = "21.1.1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltNavigationFragment" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-fragment = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment", version.ref = "hiltNavigationFragment" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltNavigationFragment" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomKtx" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomKtx" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitJunit" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-material-icons-extended = { module = "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended", version.ref = "materialIconsExtended" }

firebase-bom = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
firebase-analytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics" }
firebase-crashlytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics" }
firebase-firestore = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-firestore" }
firebase-auth = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth" }
firebase-message = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-messaging" }

gson = { group = "com.google.code.gson", name = "gson", version.ref = "gson-version" }

coil-kt-coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt:coil-compose", version.ref = "coilCompose" }
coil-svg = { module = "io.coil-kt:coil-svg", version.ref = "coilCompose" }
lottie-compose = { module = "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose", version.ref = "lottieCompose" }

richtext-commonmark = { module = "com.halilibo.compose-richtext:richtext-commonmark", version.ref = "richtextCommonmark" }
richtext-ui-material3 = { module = "com.halilibo.compose-richtext:richtext-ui-material3", version.ref = "richtextCommonmark" }

play-service-auth = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-auth", version.ref = "play-service-auth" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp-version" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltAndroidPlugin" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
googleAndroidLibrariesMapsplatformSecretsGradlePlugin = { id = "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "googleAndroidLibrariesMapsplatformSecretsGradlePlugin" }

Environment Details:

Android Studio version: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Nightly 2024-05-08
Gradle version: 8.7
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.4.0
Target Android version: 34

I was expecting the task to complete successfully and generate an optimized and obfuscated release APK file for my application. However, instead of generating the APK, the build process failed with the error.

Try removing isMinifyEnabled=true from your library module.
